# How can i report a bug about apport-gpu-error-intel.py crashing?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

Everytime my gpu crash and i have to reboot, after the boot appears:

- the window to report the gpu crash bug
- when I try to report it, apport-gpu-error-intel.py crashes
- another window appears suggesting me to report the crash of apport-gpu-error-intel.py
- then i try to report it, but when launchpad is opened I see that is reporting the original gpu bug and there is no more trace about apport-gpu-error-intel.py crash.

So, how can I report it?

UPDATE:
I know that i can report it manually, but how can I give more information, like a backtrace or something similar?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `apport-gpu-error-intel.py` belongs to the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package:

Run `dpkg -S apport-gpu-error-intel.py` to check which package contains this file:

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel: /usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.p
```

Find out the source package for the binary package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` using `apt-cache showsrc xserver-xorg-video-intel | grep '^Package:'`

```
Package: xserver-xorg-video-intel
Package: xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

In this case, the source package has the same name as the binary package (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`), but that may not always be the case (e.g. binary package `apt-utils` has source `apt`)

Bugs for that package can be reported on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bugs

Answer (score 1):

It seems like my problem began when I installed a Windows program through Wine. I deleted all of Wine's components and all of the remaining install data from the game and everything began to work fine. Maybe that just applies to me but I think everything is working okay now... fingers crossed. This issue plagued me all day long. I hope you get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can go "manually" to launchpad at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+filebug and file this bug.

It seems like it has happened before, see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/524730).

Comment: manually i would have no information apart from the fact that it crashes, I don't think would be useful. (The bug that you linked was not a good example because it has been marked as incomplete)

Comment: I'm sorry then.