# Can Ubuntu get just a little more annoying? Please?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep getting messages about internal system errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141671/keep-getting-messages-about-internal-system-errors)

Why do keep getting internal error messages, and why should I care them?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is very annoying. That's why this website exists. What kind of messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it could. That being said, without problem reporting there would be a lot more problems. What would you know what to fix if you don't know what's broken?

If there is a serious problem here is the best place to resolve it. You should care because the whole ethos of ubuntu is spirit of community. If you have a problem, share it, help is always at hand.