# How do I get rid of frequent error messages?

Tags: 12.10, beta

I am sometimes getting error messages like the ones below.

[image: System program problem]

[image: internal error]

As I [understand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141671/keep-getting-messages-about-internal-system-errors) they are from some kind of debugging mode in the beta which I sometimes install. I have no problem with them in the beta. If I install it I do because I want to report bugs. But if I switch to productivity I don't want them. Until 12.10 they stopped when the final was released and I upgraded, but not this time.

I'm not experiencing anything not working so the messages just annoy me by now. Can anyone tell me how to disable them?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it/150332

Comment: Yep, seems that way. I wouldn't call my question a duplicate but I found the answer in the other one ;-)

Comment: So what happens to this question? You can click the delete button if you think it is redundant. If you think it is worth retaining because it is genuinely different, go ahead and [answer it yourself and then accept your own answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3005/25656).

Comment: @vasa1 Just came back because I thought the same ;-) Wasn't really awake when I commented. I think it's worth retaining because the motivation for that answer is very different. Someone who has my problem will most likely not find the other question (same way as I didn't).

Comment: @stonedsquirrel That's a good reason for this to exist, but we can (and I think should) still close this. As a duplicate, it will [serve even better as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) to the master question.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm fine with closing it as long as it's not deleted.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel, I have come across a similar situation here on AU.  Why not edit the original question (the one this is being duplicated with) with your variation (the thing that makes your question unique). Especially if the same answer resolves both questions.

Comment: @StephenMyall In my opinion this is not practicable in this case. The two questions are too different. I wouldn't know how to merge them. Also it is not the full answer that is applicable to my question, only a part of it.

Comment: Problem still not solved. See comment under my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the answer by @ovc I looked up how to disable apport and found  [this question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/93467/edit).

I had to edit `/etc/default/apport` and change

```
enabled=1
```

to

```
enabled=0
```

This way it is not started at boot. For not having to reboot simply stop the service with

```
sudo service apport stop
```

Let's see if the messages disappear now :-)

Comment: I just realised that @vasa1 also linked to that question. Sorry!

Comment: Four days without a message. I think it's save to assume that this is the solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The thing which creates these error messages, as far as I know, is called Apport. You may try uninstalling that.

Comment: You're basically right I think but there is an easier than uninstalling the whole thing. See my answer.

Comment: There's no need to uninstall Apport. It can [easily be disabled or enabled](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Robie Basak I was able to find my answer in context of [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it/150332). Here is the essential part from that answer:

- Go to Settings...Privacy...

  [image]
- And in the Diagnostics Tab, *uncheck* the *Send Error Reports to Canonical* option:

  [image]

Comment: That didn't do the trick. I thought so first but the messages start appearing again :-(