# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes after update

Tags: 12.04, updates, freeze

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04 for a while now, constantly upgrading and afterwards cleaning with Ubuntu-Tweak's Janitor. Everthing went fine until about two weeks ago: then my computer constantly froze after approx. twenty seconds. Sometimes I had an error message, but not always, saying:

> "usr/share/apport/appport-gpu.error-intel.py"

Nothing helped, the problem continued. I re-installed. Then it worked again, I updated, but did not use Ubuntu Tweak. It worked, today (march 19th) I updated only and had the problem again. Recovery mode does not help.

What to do?

Comment: Same on Xubuntu 12.04 with Core i3-2125 CPU (integrated GPU) : Linux 3.2.0-39-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 00:28:53 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux It is possible that upgrading kernel to 3.5 serie (as for 12.04.2 fresh install) solve this issue ?

Comment: This is happening to me too. It started with kernel 3.2.0-39, and also happens in kernel 3.2.0-40 and 3.2.0-41. I avoid it by booting to 3.2.0-38 (at boot time, I select "previous kernels" option, or whatever it's called, and select 3.2.0-38-pae from the list).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently yesterday's update of the system kernel is botched: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127138

Try booting with the previous version. This worked for me today.

Edit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1157252

Comment: i have the same problem on ubuntu 12.04 x64. 
3.2.0-38 works fine. but update 3.2.0-39 and the new one 3.2.0-40 freeze my system after a while and i have to turn of my computer on the button.
I also have an intel graphic card. Isn't there a prettier solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found this, maybe helpful:

[Keep getting messages about internal system errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141671/keep-getting-messages-about-internal-system-errors)

[Internal error with apport-gpu-error-intel.py](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053494)

Comment: I re-installed, everything works. I did not touch the updates. What I see now, is that if I ask to update I get proposals for "security": The section on the Kernel and Xorg is unmarked - and I cannot mark it - does this mean that in general the new Kernel (..39) is not available, or what?

BR

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

http://handytutorial.com/install-linux-kernel-3-6-0-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10/

the last kernel was causing it to freeze immediately after i logged in.