# Applied maintenance to Ubuntu 12.04 (upgrade to kernel 3.2.0-39); after restart my desktop is not responding

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, telnet

After applying maintenance via Update Manager, my desktop freezes after a few seconds. There are two links on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) that mentions this as well.

Is there anything I can do to correct this problem.
BTW, the only way I can use my computer is to telnet into it. It seems to be related to going to kernel 3.2.0-39.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127138
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127155

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/269883/ubuntu-12-04-freezes-after-update

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

To get around the problem, go back to kernel `3.2.0-38`. If you are running a single OS image and you do not get a GRUB menu to allow you to select an older kernel, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during the boot process - after the BIOS Post.